# How long will the access_token expire? Or is there a refresh_token?

Tags: box-api

I want to develop an app to store my content, but I don't want the user got auth every time? I just wonder how long will the access_token will be expired or is there any refresh_token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The auth_tokens in our current system won't expire.

(note that if and when we switch to standard OAuth, this will obviously change)

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of future readers of this question, if you use OAuth2 to authenticate on Box V2 API, you will have access to a refresh token.

From https://developer.box.com/docs/faqs#section-how-do-i-automate-the-generation-of-oauth-tokens-or-run-a-server-side-solution- :

> **How do I automate the generation of OAuth tokens or run a server-side solution?**
>
> The access token is valid for around an hour.
>   The refresh token is valid for a single refresh in a 60 day period.